# DMA Transaction Packet Flow and Filtering

Tags: cpu-architecture, dma, uefi, pci-e

I want to know how exactly a DMA-Operation is performed and retrace the flow of a packet.

The origin of my question is that I want to know who enforces certain regions which are not accessible by DMA. For example, if you take a look at the following output from the [PCIe Squirrel](https://shop.lambdaconcept.com/home/50-screamer-pcie-squirrel.html) you can see that certain ranges are not accessible.

```
[+] using FTDI device: 0403:601f (bus 2, device 2)
[+] FTDIFTDI SuperSpeed-FIFO Bridge000000000001
 Memory Map:
 START              END               #PAGES
 0000000000000000 - 000000000009ffff  000000a0
 0000000000100000 - 000000006f7fffff  0006f700
 0000000078000000 - 000000007effffff  00007000

 Current Action: Probing Memory
 Access Mode:    Normal
 Progress:       2304 / 524288 (0%)
 Speed:          153 MB/s
 Address:        0x0000000090000000
 Pages read:     485280 / 134217728 (0%)
 Pages failed:   104544 (0%)
```

And I was wondering how this is enforced. My understanding is currently as follows.

```
---------------          ----------------         ------------------         -------------------------         ----------
| PCIe Device |  - TLP - | Root Complex | - ??? - | DMA-Controller | - RAW - | CPU-Memory-Controller | - RAW - | Memory |
---------------          ----------------         ------------------         -------------------------         ----------
                                                          |
                                                          |
                                                          |
                                                      --------
                                                      | UEFI |
                                                      --------
```

The `PCIe device` sends a request to the root complex, it then forwards it to the `DMA-controller` and the controller forwards the request to the in `CPU-Chiplet memory controller`. The memory controller accesses the RAM and sends the result back. The `DMA-controller` (range checks) are programmed by the UEFI on system startup. So that every UEFI reserved memory is filtered. Additionally there are other memory-protection schemes, i.e. SGX, which filter directly on the `CPU-Chiplet memory controller`.

Is my assumption so far correct or am I missing important components in the chain?

If so, is there a way to reprogram the DMA-Controller from the OS and whitelist every request?

Comment: Are you asking about a specific CPU architecture? I'm not sure there is a general answer to this question.

Comment: In systems I'm familiar with, the box you have labeled "DMA-Controller" doesn't exist. The root complex itself sends reads and writes to the memory controller. There may be an IOMMU; is that what you are referring to as DMA-Controller?

Comment: I am interested in x86. True, I forgot the MMU. Does the root complex filter in that case? Or is the UEFI directly interacting with the CPU-Memory Controller?

Comment: In an Intel system, the IOMMU is inside the root complex. Address translation is  performed after the root complex receives the transaction from the device and before the memory access is sent to the memory controller. The IOMMU can block a transaction if there is no translation for the address. See the VT-d specification for more information.

Comment: I'm not aware of any BIOS that programs the IOMMU.

Comment: In addition to the IOMMU, there are also some range registers that block access to certain regions of address space. The BIOS probably does program those. I don't know too much about them. They could be in the root complex or in the memory controller.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in those range registers and how the firmware interacts with them. I haven't found any documentation about them yet.

Comment: The SGX Explained paper contains some interesting information about it for Xeon processors (page 22). That was what I was looking for.